# Puppet in cycle added empty elements in array

Tags: puppet

```
$hash_arr_1 = { b => 2, c => 3, f => 1 }
$arr = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e']
$hash_arr_2 = $arr.map |$param| {
   if has_key($hash_arr_1, $param) {
      {$param => $hash_arr_1[$param]}
    }
}
notice($hash_arr_2)

Result: [{   , c => 3,    , f => 1,   ,}]
```

How to do that there are no empty elements in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the `map` lambda function when really you want to be using [`filter`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#filter). Summary from linked documentation is as follows:

> Applies a lambda to every value in a data structure and returns an array or hash containing any elements for which the lambda evaluates to true.

So the solution for you is:

```
$hash_arr_2 = $hash_arr_1.filter |$key, $value| { $key in $arr }
```

This will iterate through the keys of the hash `$hash_arr_1`, check if the key exists as a member of the array `$arr` with the provided conditional, and then return a hash with only the key value pairs that evaluated to true.